# Passing key value arguments from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, arguments, command-line-interface, yargs

So I'm struggling with passing command line option arguments from npm to a node script.  I can pass options themselves, but not as key value pairs.

For my package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": ". ./.env; node app.js --"
 },
```

(my understanding is that for npm you need to include and extra "--" to pass arguments)
and in my app.js I have:

```
const { argv, options } = require('yargs');
console.log(argv._);
```

When I run

```
$ npm run test FOO BAR
```

I get:

> [ 'FOO', 'BAR' ]

great, that worked, but if I try

```
$ npm run test FOO --BAR 99RedBalloons
```

I get:

> [ 'FOO', '99RedBallons' ]

and

$ npm run test FOO --BAR=99RedBallons
gives me:

> [ 'FOO' ]

Wha?  So, my question really is, using "run npm <>" and I assume yargs (since I believe that is the most popular package), how can I arrive with a arg._ of ["FOO", "Bar" : "99RedBalloons"].

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try npm run test FOO Bar 99RedBallons?

Comment: I have, and that gives me [ 'FOO', 'Bar', '99RedBalloons' ]

Comment: There something weird to me how npm is passing command line arguments to the node script

Comment: I thought you wanted the exact result you say in your comment and the end of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, according to the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), you must pass extra " -- " to specify arguments to an *npm* script, but you do not pass it at the right place.

You do not need to pass it at the end of your `package.json` "test" script, but directly in the command line which **call** your script.

This way, *npm* understand it is arguments for your script and not for the *npm* command itself:

```
// cli
$ npm run test -- FOO --BAR 99RedBalloons    // "--" before arguments
  /* or */
$ npm run test -- FOO --BAR=99RedBalloons

// package.json
"scripts": {
   "test": ". ./.env; node app.js"
 }

// app.js
const { argv } = require('yargs');
console.log(argv);

// -> { _: [ 'FOO' ], BAR: '99RedBalloons', '$0': 'app.js' }
```

I did not find a *yargs* built-in option to do it, but alternatively, if you want all your arguments in the `_` array variable, you can do something like this:

```
for (let cmd in argv)
  if (cmd !== '$0' && cmd !== '_')
    argv._[cmd] = argv[cmd]

console.log(argv._)

// -> [ 'FOO', BAR: '99RedBalloons' ]
```